# Doctrine migrations very slow on vagrant

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, database-migration

I'm running vagrant on my osX.
I'm using the zend framework 2 doctrine module.
While I was using it in native apache it was working fast.

Now on vagrant every migrations:diff or validate-schema is sooooo slow. It takes about 1 minute, or more to generate a migration file or to check the schema.

Comment: Are you dealing with loads of data? You might want to try and increase the amount of memory for the virtual machine.

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of data. Also a lot of entities (about 40-50). I've got 2GB of memory for the virtual machine.